# invariant violaion.objects are not valid as react child issue in react-native

Tags: react-native

When I am trying to wrap redux form into the react-native elements it shows following error.

[image]

this is my code

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Field,reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Text,Input } from 'react-native-elements';
import { View,Button } from 'react-native';

 const renderField=({label,keyboardType,name}) => {
    return(
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row',height:50,alignItems:'center' }}>
                <Text>
                    {label}
                </Text>
                <Input />
            </View>
    )
}

const RegisterForm=props => {
    const {handleSubmit}=props;
    return(
            <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',margin:40,justifyContent:'flex-start'}}>

                <Field label="Username" component={renderField} name="username" />
                <Button title='SUBMIT' onPress={handleSubmit} />

            </View>
    )
}
const Register=reduxForm({
    form:'register',
})(RegisterForm);
export default Register;
```

When used FormInput in react-native elements it works then I am changed it into react-native elements 1.0.0beta4 and replace the formInput with Input component.
After that it shows above error.My debugger window also shows an error

**debugger window**
[image]

Comment: You are still using `<FormInput />` in renderField

Comment: sorry that's my mistake.still having same error after changing it into Input component  and restart the project

Comment: please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: i am edited the question with the image of debugger window.please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to your upgrade to `react-native-elements beta` which include breaking changes like the [button component props](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html) :

The actual error is located in `welcomePage.js` file (as you can see in debugger), you need to change the object you pass to the button icon prop to a react  component (see the button doc in the link above).

Comment: when i trying to install react-native in linux it doen't work,after i followed this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows/47035389] helps me to solve the problem.

Comment: but I am failed to open the debugger window,i will uploaded the issue in 1hr and sent that link.can you help me?

Comment: please check this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768865/unable-to-connect-with-remote-logger-issue-in-react-nativeandroid-in-linux]