# unable to connect with remote debugger unexpected end of stream on connection issue in react-native(android) in linux

Tags: react-native

When I am trying to connect to remote debugger it shows following error.
[image]

react version: 16.3.1,
react-native version : 0.55.2

tried with adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 and react-native start,but when I select the debug window still showing the above error.

Comment: Possibly you will get answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898934/unable-to-connect-with-remote-debugger

Comment: React Native used port `8081`, so dont `reverse tcp:8081` in adb, try `adb tcpip:5555`

Comment: i am tried with adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Comment: @NikhilParmar I also check it,but nothing helped

Comment: open new tab http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui and then try again to debug. and don't forget to do adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 running react-native run-android.

Comment: i open it in a new tab after doing the adb reverse command i restart the project,but when i go to the tab it shows 'site can't be reached ' message.

Comment: I am failed to see my debugging screen when i go to the url.what  the issue is here?

Answer (score 4):

Try to add your **ip-address:8081** in Dev setting ==> debug server host and port for device...

Comment: didn't work, and it's stopped taking commands form `adb shell input text rr', after this, and after Undoing, it would work.